# Unable to access Jboss 4.3.0-GA using IP address

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, jboss-4.2.x

I have Jboss server 4.3.0-GA version running on my machine Windows7 - 64 bit. When i access the server using localhost/127.0.0.1 it can be accessible, but if i mention my IP address(IPV4) then it is unavailable. I have followed the below solution, but is of no use:

```
run.bat -b 0.0.0.0

run.bat -b <<IP address>>
```

Could someone please get me out of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing run.bat from

```
org.jboss.Main "-c" "default"
```

to

```
org.jboss.Main -b0.0.0.0
```

has done the trick. But it forces you to create new profile for production exactly as it is the one like default.

Answer (score 1):

you can place your ip in place of 0.0.0.0 then you can access via your ip
like run.bat -b 192.168.0.155

also make sure you have the entry in host file if using some of url to access jboss

Comment: Tried with my IP address, but no use.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to do exactly

Comment: I have an appication runming on my local on Jboss server. I wpant to access the same application on Ipad. Since I cannot access jboss on Ipad using localhost/127.0.0.1, I am using my IP address.

Comment: Also where is the host file to make an entry.

Comment: If I am correct you are having two device one on which you are running your server let we call it A and second on which you want to access your server we call it B. In this case first make sure your A is having an public IP accessible to network . try a ping from device B to A using the IP of device A. Now if ping is success check that the server is accessible to Device B or not using telnet command , if you are using windows & make sure to enable telnet before use. telnet Ip of Device A with Jboss Port default is 1099.

Comment: If all of above work then your application is accessible to Device B

Comment: Thanks for ur detailed steps.... I just wanted to let you know that, when I use the tomcat I don't have any problem. Tomcat that is  running on device A  is accessible from device device B. Still is there anything to do with telnet IP for JBoss.

Comment: If I am correct you are trying to access the web component from Device B. For that you have to use web port of Jboss rather RMI port say if your RMI port is 1099 use 8080 to access.

Comment: Yes, I am using 8080 port to access the server, Device B is IPad, in which i am trying to access the Jboss server.

Comment: Finally got it working on Ipad by placing 'org.jboss.Main -b0.0.0.0' in the run.bat file.

Comment: Thank you very much dude for following up with me and for your valuable time.